# Martingale convergnce theorem application

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, martingales, expected-value

I'm trying to solve the following exercise which requires the application of martingale convergence thm.

> Let $(M_n)_n$ be a martingale w.r.t $(F_n)_n$ and let
>
> $$C_n = M_n - M_{n-1}, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$
>
> Prove that if $E[M_0^2] < \infty$ and $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[C_n^2] < \infty$, then there exists a r.v. $M$ such that $M_n \rightarrow M$ a.s. and in $L^2$.

---

What I need to do is to show that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}E[M_n^2] < \infty$, in order to apply the theorem mentioned above.

I've seen on the inernet that if $(M_n)_n$ is a square integrable martingale, then the increments $C_n$ are orthogonal in $L^2$ and I can write $$E[M_n^2] = E[M_0^2] + \sum_{k=1}^n  E[C_n^2] , \quad (\star)$$.

If I know this, of course I'm done since I can take the supremum both sides and use the convergence of the series and the finitess of $E[M_0^2]$ and I get the thesis.

---

So, my questions are:

- Is my martingale square integrable? I can't show it.
- How the independence of the increments imply ($\star$) ?
- Are there other ways to attack the problem?

Comment: For the first question I think you need to expand $E[C_{n},C_{n-1}]=E[M_{n}M_{n-1}]-E[M_{n}M_{n-2}]-E[M_{n-1}M_{n-1}]+E[M_{n-1}M_{n-2}]$. Then use the "tower property" of conditional expectations $E[M_{n}M_{n-1}]=E[M_{n}M_{n-1}|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]=M_{n-1}E[M_{n}|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]$. Using the martingale property you then get $E[M_{n}M_{n-1}]=M_{n-1}^{2}$. Repeating something like this term by term I believe you can get $E[C_{n},C_{n-1}]=E[0]=0$ showing $C_{n}\perp C_{n-1}$

Comment: You can then do $E\left[\sum_{n}C_{n}^{2}\right]=\sum_{n}Var(C_{n})+\left[\sum_{n}E[C_{n}]\right]^{2}+\sum_{n}\sum_{m<n}Cov[C_{n},C_{m}]=\sum_{n}Var(C_{n})+\left[\sum_{n}E[C_{n}]\right]^{2}=\sum_{n}E[C_{n}^{2}]$. I think this sort of reasoning might get you somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> What I need to do is to show that $\sup_{ n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}[M_{n}^{2}]<\infty$, in order to apply the theorem mentioned above.

As already mentioned, it is enough to show that

> $\mathbb{E}[M_n^2] = \mathbb{E}[M_0^2] + \sum_{k=1}^n  \mathbb{E}[C_k^2] , \quad (\star)$

because we then simply have

$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}[M_{n}^{2}] \le \mathbb{E}{M_{0}^{2}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[C_{k}^{2}],$$
which is finite by assumption.

> I've seen on the inernet that if $(M_{n})_{n}$ is a square integrable martingale, then the increments $C_{n}$ are orthogonal in $L^{2}$.

OK, but it is also enough to know, that increments are square integrable. Let us explain it in more details.

For simplicity put $M_{0}:=C_{0}$.

$$\mathbb{E}[M_{n}^{2}]=\mathbb{E}[(C_{0}+\cdots C_{n})^2]=\mathbb{E}[M_{0}^2]+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[C_{k}^2]+\sum_{0\le i \not{=}j \le n}\mathbb{E}{C_{i}C_{j}}.$$

We will show that for every $i\not= j$ we have $\mathbb{E}[C_{i}C_{j}]=0$, which will prove $(\star)$.

Because $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[C_{k}^{2}] <+\infty$, then $\mathbb{E}[C_{k}^2]$ is obviously finite for all $k$.

Suppose that $i<j$, then $$\mathbb{E}{C_{i}C_{j}}= \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[C_{i}C_{j}|\mathcal{F}_{i} ] \Big],$$ 
Note that we are using here tower property of expectation and finiteness of second moments

- Cauchy- Schwarz inequality tells us that $C_{i}C_{j}$ is in fact integrable and the whole business with conditional expectations makes sense.

Let us now look closer into inside expectation. Since $C_{i}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{i}$ measurable, we have

$$\mathbb{E}[C_{i}C_{j}|\mathcal{F}_{i}]=C_{i}\cdot \mathbb{E}[C_{j}|F_{i}].$$

We will now use matringale property to see, that last term is equal to zero.

$$\mathbb{E}[C_{j}|F_{i}]=\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[C_{j}|F_{j-1}]\Big|F_{i}\Big]=0.$$

In last equality we have used the following:

- $i<j$ implies that $i\le j-1.$
- $\mathbb{E}[C_{j}|F_{j-1}]=0$.

To see the second dot, simply write:

$\mathbb{E}[C_{j}|F_{j-1}]= \mathbb{E}[M_{j}-M_{j-1}|F_{j-1}]=0 \iff \mathbb{E}[M_{j}|F_{j-1}]=M_{j-1}.$

Now for the questions:

> Is my martingale square integrable? I can't show it.

Now we can say that it is.

> How the independence of the increments imply (⋆) ?

I think it is visible in the posted proof, but be aware that independence is something different then $\mathbb{E}[C_{i}C_{j}]=0$, that we have actually used.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and for your time! I'll take the time to give a closer look :)

Comment: You are welcome! :)

Comment: Very nice explanation and obviously far better than my hurried comments earlier! In terms of $\mathbb{E}{C_{i}C_{j}}= \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[C_{i}C_{j}|\mathcal{F}_{i} ] \Big]$ can the left hand term $\mathbb{E}{C_{i}C_{j}}$ be written something like $\mathbb{E}{C_{i}C_{j}}=\mathbb{E}[{C_{i}C_{j}|\mathcal{F}_{0}}]$ where $F_{0}$ is the earliest sigma-field? I am just interested to see how unconditional expectation can be cast (trivially) in terms of a conditional one

Comment: Thank You. :) I don't think that $\mathbb{E}C_{i}C_{j}=\mathbb{E}[C_{i}C_{j}|\mathcal{F}_{0}]$ because $M_{0}$ is not necessarily a constant, and hence $\mathcal{F}_{0}$ is not necessarily trivial. So left hand side is a number, and right one might be random variable.

Comment: Ahh thank-you I see I was confused: Let $\mathcal{H}=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ so that $\mathcal{H}\subseteq \mathcal{F}_{n}$ for all $n$ - i.e. all $\sigma$-fields in the filtration are sub-$\sigma$-fields of $\mathcal{H}$. Since the only $\mathcal{H}$-measurable functions are constant functions, by the definition of conditional expectation $E[X|\mathcal{H}]=E(X)$ for any random variable.

Comment: Unleashing the tower property on $M_{n}$ we get $E[E[M_{n}|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]|\mathcal{H}]=E[M_{n}|\mathcal{H}]$ the left side becomes $E[E[M_{n}|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]|\mathcal{H}]=E[E[M_{n}|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]]$ and the right side $E[M_{n}|\mathcal{H}]=E[M_{n}]$. Thus $E[E[M_{n}|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]]=E[M_{n}]=E[M_{n}|\mathcal{H}]$ so I guess I was confused between $\mathscr{F}_{0}$, the smallest (coarsest?) $\sigma$-field in the filtration $\mathscr{F}_{0}\subseteq \mathscr{F}_{1}\subseteq\mathscr{F}_{2}\subseteq...$ and $\mathcal{H}$

Comment: which is in fact the coarsest $\sigma$-field possible, i.e. $\mathcal{H}\subseteq\mathscr{F}_{0}\subseteq \mathscr{F}_{1}\subseteq\mathscr{F}_{2}\subseteq...$. Thus applying this also to $C_{i}C_{j}$ gives $E[C_{i}C_{j}]=E[C_{i}C_{j}|\mathcal{F}_{i}]$