# Martingale convergence and simple random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, solution-verification, random-walk

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $(X_n)_n $ be  a collection of i.i.d $L^2$ random variables, with $E[X_n]=0 ,E[X_n^2]=1$ and let $S_n = X_1 + \ldots X_n$.
>
> Show that can't exists a random variable $X$ such that $S_n \rightarrow X$ a.s.
>
> Hint: If $S_n$ converges, then $X_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s.

---

First question:

- I can't undestand the hint:
  **Why if $S_n$ converges, then $X_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s. ?**

---

- Second question is about my attempt, just using the hint

Attempt:

Since $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N} } E[X_n^2] = 1$, I have that the martingale $(X_n)_n$ is $L^2$-bounded, therefore converges a.s. and in $L^2$. By hint it converges to $0$, and the $L^2$ convergence  implies that $\lim_{n} E[X_n^2] = E[0]$.

But that's a contradiction since the limit on the left is exactly $1$, while the rhs is $0$.

Is it okay?

Comment: Why $\{X_n\}$ is a martingale?
If $S_n$ converges, then $S_{n-1}$ also converges to the same limit and $X_n=S_n-S_{n-1}\to X-X=0$ a.s.

Comment: If $X_n$ are iid then $X_n\to 0$ a.s. iff $X_n=0$ a.s. for any $n$.

Comment: @NCh I understand your first comment, indeed I made a big mistake by using the martingale convergence thm to $(X_n)_n$.
But I can't understand how your second comment could help

Comment: The a.s. convergence implies convergence to $0$ in distribution. But the distributions of $X_n$ do not depend on $n$. In order to $F_{X_n}(x) \to F_0(x)=P(0\leq x)$ for all $x\neq 0$, $F_{X_n}(x)$ must coincide with $F_0(x)$.

Comment: @NCh but where are you using that $E[X_n] =0$ and $E[X_n^2] = 1$?

Comment: $\mathbb E[0^2]=0\neq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative proof which does not use the hint. Suppose for contradiction that $S_n$ converged a.s. to some random variable $X$. Then $X/\sqrt{n}$ converges a.s. to $0$. But this contradicts the central limit theorem, which states that $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ converges a.s. to an $N(0,1)$ random variable.

Comment: Why do you say that $\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges a.s. to $0$?

Comment: For every real number $x\in\mathbb R$, the sequence $x/\sqrt{n}$ converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus by the definition of a.s. convergence, for any random variable $X$ the sequence $X/\sqrt{n}$ converges a.s. to $0$.

Comment: thanks! It's clear now :)

Comment: I have a similar answer, if you can have a look it would be great https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504294/martingale-convergnce-theorem-application